# combine rowPerc, colPerc in one matrix?

Tags: r

Suppose I have data with sales of different products in different categories in different months and I want to see their percentage of sales or number of items in each category

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     2     5      8     1        X    K     John
1    A     2     6      9     2        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
2    B     2     4      6     1        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     3      4     2        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     5      7     3        X    L      Sam
3    C     2     5     11     1        X    M     John
3    C     2     5     11     2        X    L     John
3    C     2     5     11     3        X    K     John
4    D     2     8     10     1        Y    M     John
4    D     2     8     10     2        Y    K     John
4    D     2     5      7     3        Y    K     John
5    E     2     5      9     1        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     2        Y    L      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
6    F     2     4      7     1        Z    M     Kyle
6    F     2     5      8     2        Z    L     Kyle
6    F     2     5      8     3        Z    M     Kyle
```

applying `table` on category and mode will show us how many times particular category existed under particular mode

```
    K L M
  X 4 4 1
  Y 2 1 3
  Z 0 1 2
```

Now `rowPerc` and `colPerc` will give us either percentage on row wise or column wise. 
But what if I am interested to know for example X/K makes up how much percentage of the total data which is 22.22% (total data in matrix is 18). 
Is there any way I can get a matrix of percentage of particular point in total data. 
something like this

```
        K      L      M 
  X  22.22  22.22   5.55 
  Y  11.11  5.55    16.67 
  Z  0.00   5.55    11.11
```

so total sum of matrix is 100% instead of rows or column.

I hope I explained it clearly. Thanks

Comment: If `df` is your data.frame, `with(df, prop.table(table(Category, Mode))*100)`.

Comment: @Pascal I didn't see your comment while posting it.  I noticed that you posted it before.  I will delete it.

Comment: @akrun  No problem, you can keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your data.frame

`with(df, prop.table(table(Category, Mode))*100)`